# AXIOS and FETCH not getting custom errors in NODE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch

I am trying to catch the custom error I've created in the back end but Axios and fetch are not getting the `res.status(401).json({msg:"custom error name"})`
I've been getting the response from catch but there is no error no msg there

```
try {
  const loginUser = { email: user.email, password: user.password };
  const loginRes = await Axios.post(
    "http://localhost:4000/snackhub/login",
    loginUser
  );
  localStorage.setItem("auth-token", loginRes.data.token);
  dispatch(fetchUsers());
  history.push("/");
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.response);
  err.response.data.msg && console.log(err.response.data.msg); //hopefully i can display this thhe custom error from the backend
}
```

Here are the examples of errors in the backend:

```
 const { error } = await logInValidation(req.body);
if (error) return res.status(400).json({ msg: error.message[0].details }); //is there something wrong in my syntax here?

const userExists = await Customer.findOne({ email: email });
if (!userExists)
  return res.status(400).json({ msg: "email is not registered" });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and I figured out a way to fix this. You can try `console.log(error.response.data)`. This will print the JSON response sent from your server...
i.e : `res.status({message: "Custom error message"})`
can be accessed using axios on the client side by using:

```
axios.get(url)
.then(response => {
    // your logic 
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response.data.message)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:4000/snackhub/login",
    loginUser)
.then(res => {
                        
},
error => {

}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

for send error or any response you should write like this.

```
res.status(422).send({ success: false, error: "User already exist!" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Error handling in `axios` is little bit different from others. Here, you get the `response` object in the error object in the `catch` block. I would recommend you to log the response and then to handle it accordingly.

One example is this:

```js
axios.post(url, data).then(res => {
        // do good things
})
.catch(err => {
    if (err.response) {
      // client received an error response (5xx, 4xx)
    } else if (err.request) {
      // client never received a response, or request never left
    } else {
      // anything else
    }
})
```